# How to share kotlin code in IntelliJ IDEA between desktop, android and server?

Tags: android, intellij-idea, kotlin, server, desktop-application

I'm developing a new client and server. The client needs to support android and desktop (Windows, Mac, Linux). The server only needs to support Linux. Both will be written in Kotlin.

I hope to be able build 3 things:

- An Android client APK
- A desktop client JAR
- A server JAR

I want to share code between all 3 of these.

How do I go about setting this up in IntelliJ IDEA 2019.1?

I have viewed the options under 'New Project' -> 'Kotlin', but I don't know which ones to select, as they don't appear to cover all my needs.

---

**Edit1:**

I started with 'New Project' -> Gradle.

I checked 'Kotlin DSL build script' and 'Kotlin/JVM'.

Entered artifactid, groupid and version.

Now I have a few options, I'm not sure what I need to enter on the next page. I assume I would want 'auto-import', I don't know about any of the other options though. I'm not familiar enough with Gradle.

Answer (score 1):

Set it up as a new Gradle project, with multiple builds. You're going to have 'common' code, 'mobile' code, 'desktop' code, and 'server' code. You might also have a need for 'client' common code, which is only used for the mobile and desktop builds.

Then, read through the Gradle documentation on multiple builds [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html). It can be hard to get right, but I hope I've given you a good starting point.

Comment: I have updated my post.

Comment: All your answers are in the documentation I linked to.

Comment: @bluelightzero If I was able to lead you to the solution you were seeking, feel free to mark  accepted